# Self sizing cell with two dynamic height UILabels

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I create a custom `UITableViewCell` that contains a title text (`UILabel1`) and a message text (`UILabel2`). Both of them are multiline labels and are populated from model class. I'm trying to use the iOS 8 self sizing feature. It works fine when the `UILabel1` has fixed height constraint (one line of text), then `UILabel2` extends the height dynamically and it works. But I need `UILabel1` be flexible height too.

Any ideas how to to this?

A picture illustrates what I want achieve:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by setting the priorities for constraints

Comment: Yes `content hugging` and `content compression` priorities did play main role here.